# What is MPC-LIFENET port 1213?

Tags: port

My 'Download Master' client tries to connect to this port on my new Asus router.
Without succes of course, because it does not seem to be running.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the port used by the router's torrent service

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ASUS utility "Download Master" is a torrent client, which give you ability to download torrents with a help of your router to harddisk drive, connected by USB to that router. In configuration menu of your router you have to enable this feature and, of course, to install an external harddisk/usb flash/etc (because router needs place for saving downloaded files)

Comment: Yes you're right. But i did all those.. but it does not work.. while connecting to that port the router resets the connection. Do you know that service?

Comment: Asus routers support custom firmware, try searching famous "Oleg's firmware", you will get linux and can install transmission/rtorrent client, which worked fine for me. I also had troubles with Download Master, so I wiped out Asus firmware and installed custom one.

Comment: Yeah I know DD WRT. I've been using it for about a year on my old Asus WL520GU. But I got the newest Asus RT N16 for which there is no firmware.. and won't be that soon.

Comment: That's poor, try asking on asus forums, I am not sure that ServerFault users know much about asus =).

Comment: Alright.. that was the reason why I didnt ask about the Asus router, instead if anyone knows that lifenet service :)